# Could you please tell me the time?

Tags: popularity-contest

You know that your language's clock/time API's are broken and they are not reliable at all.

So you are not allowed to use any built-in API to access system time/date.

But you also know that your language's ability to perform date math, and retaining a date/time value in a variable are correct.

Write a program that prints the current date/time without calling any date/time/clock API's.  For example `DateTime.Now`, `GetDate()` and similar functions are not allowed.

The answer with most upvotes wins.

In case of a tie, the answer with more precision wins (that is, accurate up to seconds, then milliseconds, then microseconds, and so on).

Comment: In other words, talk to a time server?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.  One possible solution.

Comment: Rather unspecific question. I guess the most votes will be gathered by an answer like `print(input("Please enter the current time"))`.

Comment: @Howard Is that banned by our standard loopholes? It should be.

Comment: My money is on "Load REPL for different language and call its non-broken time API."

Comment: Can I call library functions that call something like `GetDate()` in its definition?

Comment: @swich that is also not allowed.  Because your answer will become unreliable.

Comment: To clarify - the system time is correct, but all the standard APIs are broken? Or is the machine time incorrect as well?

Comment: System time is correct, it is only your language that when it tries to read system clock, it reads the wrong value.

Comment: Sorry for the unconstructive comment here, but: The time is 9:35 and it is the 11th of March 2014 :)
Back to the Q = Nice question :) 
Are we allowed to open web pages?

Comment: Yes, you can do it.  I want to see your solution.

Comment: Since i can't post an answer, I'll just leave it here:
python:
`current_time = input("I know it sound's weird but my clock is broken. Could you tell me the accurate time please? I'm talking micro-seconds here. Thanks in advance.")`

Comment: Another option (a bit more serious this time):
constantly send GET request for which the response include the "Date" header. Parse the time from the "Date" header only the first time you receive it - but continue to request it. When the received "Date" changes you know you are a short time after a cycle, which get's you a bit more accurate. Continue to do so until you get banned for performing D.O.S attack on the site.

Comment: After that move to another site. This method is called para-site.

Answer (score 122):

## Java

Almost all of the current solutions assume that local/remote computer is not lying about a current time (would you believe T-600 as well?) . 
 
Key point in time calculation is trusting a **pure nature**. 
This Android app asks user to take photo of the sky and it's predicting current time with outstanding precision:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
   {
      Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
      this.imageView.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);

      TimeGuesser guesser = new TimeGuesser(this);
      String result = guesser.guessTimeFromImage(selectedImageUri);
      this.textView.setText(result);   
   }
}

public class TimeGuesser {

    private Context context;
    public TimeGuesser(Context context)
    {
        super();
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String guessTimeFromImage(Uri uri) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.context.getContentResolver(), uri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "There is no sky. Everyone's going to die";
        }

        float brightness = getBrightness(bitmap);

        if (brightness < 90.0)
        {
            return "It's sooo late";
        } else {
            return "It's sooo early";
        }
    }

    private float getBrightness(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        float R, G, B;
        R = G = B = 0.0f;
        int pixelColor;
        int width = bitmap.getWidth();
        int height = bitmap.getHeight();
        int size = width * height;

        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
                pixelColor = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
                R += Color.red(pixelColor);
                G += Color.green(pixelColor);
                B += Color.blue(pixelColor);
            }
        }

        R /= size;
        G /= size;
        B /= size;

        float brightness =  (0.2126f*R ) + (0.7152f*G) + (0.0722f*B);
        return brightness;
    }
}
```

### Results:

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: +1 for `"There is no sky. Everyone's going to die"` :D

Comment: "Everyone's going to die - or your finger is over the camera. Basically the same thing."

Comment: Please specify Java

Comment: This is definitely my favorite, I just hope it doesn't come down to a tiebreaker...

Comment: @corsiKa: putting your finger over the camera probably won't raise an exception though.

Comment: What about sunsets?  Will it say it is early?

Comment: Some places this app only works during spring and autumn.

Comment: What about Eclipses? They're likely to cause as much of a problem here as they do during Java development!

Comment: You sure live in a beautiful neighborhood.

Comment: @DrEval "Eclipses" Was this an intended pun?

Answer (score 64):

## Ruby

Let's be honest: time only changes when something is posted on [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) ;)

The script extracts the time of the "XYs ago" label in the topmost question.

```ruby
require 'net/http'
source = Net::HTTP.get('stackoverflow.com', '/')

puts source.match(/span title=\"(.*)\" class=\"relativetime/)[1]
```

Output:

```
2014-03-10 18:40:05Z
```

Comment: Only accurate to the second...and the second that SO pings its ntp..shameful worship

Comment: THE <CENTER> CANNOT HOLD **HE COMES**

Comment: @Doorknob I really need to print out that post and hang it on my wall.

Answer (score 30):

### Bash

Like this? (requires `wget` and `grep`)

```
wget -qO- 'http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=current+time'|grep ' am \| pm '
```

The output I got a few minutes ago:

```
                    Why am I seeing this message? 
  context.jsonArray.popups.pod_0200.push( {"stringified": "6:08:38 pm GMT\/BST  |  Monday, March 10, 2014","mInput": "","mOutput": "", "popLinks": {} });
```

Or this? (requires `wget` and `eog`)

```
wget http://c.xkcd.com/redirect/comic/now
eog ./now
rm ./now
```

Output I get now: (Image by [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/1335/))

[world map with timezone http://c.xkcd.com/redirect/comic/now](http://c.xkcd.com/redirect/comic/now)

Comment: @tbodt Not sure whether you will see this comment. Your edit is invalid because `http://c.xkcd.com/redirect/comic/now` gives an image while `http://xkcd.com/now` gives a webpage.

Comment: I only just realised that the comic displayed changes depending on the time of day. That's awesome.

Comment: It's a pity the cartoon doesn't incorporate daylight saving.  (For example, the eastern US is only four hours behind the UK as I write this, not the normal five that the cartoon shows.) More significantly, the northern and southern hemispheres can move two hours out of synch.

Comment: I say +1 to xkcd for **not** observing daylight saving time, and hope the rest of the world follows suit.

Answer (score 29):

## sh/coreutils

```
touch . && stat . -c %z
```

Outputs the date in somewhat nonstandard format:
`YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.nanoseconds +timezone`
Although I guess it might depend on the locale.

Comment: Doesn't work.  It says _permission denied_ :)

Comment: @devnull your filesystem is terribly broken. Fix it with `cd $(mktemp -d)`

Comment: Meh, the dir time is set using a library function.

Comment: @Navin It isn't set. The directory inode is just opened for writing, and kernel updates its mtime. There's no explicit  `set mtime to this` syscall happening anywhere

Comment: @mniip Welll, alright. I still feel that `touch` is a library function/command since it has the desired side effect.

Answer (score 25):

### PHP

Exploit the fact that `uniqid()` returns an ID based on the time.

```php
$u=hexdec(substr(uniqid(),0,8));

$y=floor($u/31536000);
$u-=$y*31536000;
$y+=1970;

$d=floor($u/86400);
$u-=$d*86400;

$h=floor($u/3600);
$u-=$h*3600;

$m=floor($u/60);

$s=$u-$m*60;

echo 'Year='.$y.' Days='.$d.' Hours='.$h.' Minutes='.$m.' Seconds='.$s;
```

During my test, it returned : `Year=2014 Days=79 Hours=18 Minutes=9 Seconds=49`.
I don't know if I can use `date` to format correctly, so I converted it manually.

Comment: I'm sure this is bending of the rules... `uniqid` is still a part of your language... But still you get a +1

Comment: Why ? yes, `uniqid` use low level time API but even when you request time from an external server there will be a low level call to time API somewhere...

Comment: I'm not speaking of time API calls here. I'm saying that it's still a part of the language.

Comment: @mniip yes, but `uniqid()` was broken before this question was even asked. only the clock/time APIs are broken in this question

Answer (score 24):

**Bash**

Just to be always absolutely precise and correct:

```
echo "Now"
```

or motivating:

```
echo "Now, do something useful today"
```

Comment: toady, noun, plural toadies. An obsequious flatterer; sycophant. ([Source](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/toady))

Comment: Not `absolutely precise`, running the command will still take some teeny-weeny bit of time.

Comment: @user80551 And thats were you are wrong, now is always perfectly precise. If you look at your watch time changes before the image reaches your eye. But now, now is always now.

Comment: @ace Thank you for enlightening me.

Comment: @Master117 Nope, I want the time ***exactly*** when I hit the enter key. Since `echo Now` is not *instantaneous* , there is some time lag between me hitting enter and bash echoing "Now".

Comment: @user80551 that means the time isnt there instantly but its result is still perfectly precise when it arrives

Comment: @Master117 By that logic, all answers will be invalid one second later.

Comment: @user80551 `echo "Then"` works for that requirement.

Comment: -What the hell I'm looking at? When this it's happening in the program?

-Now! You are looking at Now sir, whatever it's happening now in the program it's happening now.

-What append to then?

-It's passed

-When?

-Just now

Comment: The second solution is without doubts even better than my solution.

Comment: @ace maybe the script wanted a new feature added to Dwarf Fortress

Answer (score 23):

## DNS

Do we only mistrust our own machine? If so, does this count?

```
ssh $othermachine date
```

If that doesn't count, extracting time from DNS update definitely does:

```
dig stackexchange.com | grep WHEN
```

Answer (score 20):

## curl - accurate to whatever your ping rate is

```
curl -s time.nist.gov:13
```

Comment: Nice, but it's in UTC, shouldn't it be in local time?

Comment: @orion Aren't we local to the universe?

Comment: This is one of the 2 default servers that windows uses to sync the time.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel it is also used by many non-standard systems..

Comment: I'm just saying. I'm not saying it is the only place where it is used. I'm just telling a fact.

Comment: Some of these timeservers don't respond on IPv6, so this may fail.

Comment: `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`

Comment: Some “non-standard systems” have their kernel run in UTC since it makes more sense for logfiles. How about your “standard system”?

Comment: Where in the OP does the challenge mention "Local" time?  I'm befuddled as to why I am getting these comments from @orion and queueoverflow

Comment: I just commented because the returned time may differ from what you would get from `date` and since you are replacing it, it needs postprocessing. However, I absolutely agree that UTC is the only sensible option of internal timekeeping for an OS&hardware. Otherwise you fly to a different timezone and everything becomes crippled.

Answer (score 14):

## Python

You sure you don't know what time is it?!? Here's a reminder:

```
print "It's Adventure Time!"
```

Comment: It's clobberin' time :)

Answer (score 13):

## Python 2

So, the clock is correct but the time API is hosed, right? Why not check a raw filesystem timestamp. Instead of creating a test file, we just use our own access timestamp since the script *has* to be read to run (even if it's been compiled). Accurate to the second.*

```
import os
h, m = divmod(os.stat('t.py').st_atime % 86400, 3600)
print h+1, m // 60, m % 60
```

This should be saved and run as `t.py`. Alternately, get the script name at runtime with `inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())`

Note * Occasionally accurate to the *previous* second.

Comment: Should we check `t.pyc` or `t.pyo` instead?

Comment: Good thinking but these won't exist unless you import this file as a module (or create them manually). Anyway I checked and python (2.7.2 on OS X) will touch the `.py` file even if the corresponding `.pyc` is present. So this always works correctly.

Comment: Noted and upvoted. Nicely done.

Answer (score 10):

### Ruby

HTTP, but just using response meta-data.

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

def get_now
  uri = URI.parse("http://google.com")
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
  rsp = http.request(request)
  rsp['date']
end
```

Answer (score 9):

## ps

Can't `ps` tell the time?  It can!

```
sleep 1&  ps -o lstart -p $!
```

The process is started in the background and `ps` tells the time the process started.   Since the process started in the background, the start time of the process is *pretty much* the same time as now.

Moreover, the advantage is that the time is obtained in the local time zone.  And you don't need a internet connection either!

Answer (score 7):

### vba

because I shouldn't.

```
Public Function DateTime() As String
Dim myNTPsvr As String
Dim dattime As String
Dim oHTTP As Object

myNTPsvr = "time.windows.com"
Set oHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
oHTTP.Open "GET", "http://" & myNTPsvr & "/", False
oHTTP.Send

DateTime = oHTTP.GetResponseHeader("Date")

Set oHTTP = Nothing
End Function
```

use `?DateTime` to use, or if you put it into Excel, then `=DateTime()` will work as a formula.
The date/time is returned in GMT - I leave it as an exercise in futility to convert it from a string to local time

Answer (score 6):

## Bash + `last` + `head` + `cut`

Precise to the second. `last` uses the log file `/var/log/wtmp`

```
$ last -RF reboot | head -n1 | cut -c50-73
Tue Mar 11 09:38:53 2014
$
```

EDIT: Added `head` to limit to only one line.

EDIT: This works on Linux Mint 13 Cinnamon 64-bit but it seems that this is depends on your distro. `sysvinit-utils` (which provides `last`) version is `2.88dsf-13.10ubuntu11.1` `last` reads from `/var/log/wtmp` (in my case) so the results depend on that log file. See comments below.

EDIT: Apparently this depends on the system uptime so you can see the proof here https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVS5B.jpg

Comment: That returns an empty line here. And I am not sure anything relevant can be extracted from there, as man `last` says “The pseudo user reboot logs in each time the system is rebooted.” (And not even that seems to be correct here: http://pastebin.com/ArUaBcuY )

Comment: @manatwork http://imgur.com/SeJX9RA Actually, `-F` prints full login and **logout** times. As the current user is still logged in, the logout time is the current time. This is on Linux Mint 13 cinnamon 64 bit. It might be locale dependent but I doubt it.

Comment: @manatwork It works [here too](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_bash_online.php)

Comment: I see. So the relevant lines are completely missing here on a Frugalware 1.9 and an Ubuntu 12.04. But almost worked on an ancient Sorcerer: `last` output the log lines, but had no `-F` switch. Anyway, it confirmed your code is correct.

Comment: Er, this should work on 12.04, LM13 uses it as its base. btw what do you mean by `ancient Sorcerer`

Comment: This is my man page http://pastebin.com/TW2Qm0jH

Comment: No idea. By the way, the Ubuntu machine I can access only through `ssh`, not sure whether that affects `last`. http://pastebin.com/DFTd2cTq

Comment: @manatwork Mine has 12.04. **4** What's the version of `sysvinit-utils`? http://pastebin.com/krMeYv9u

Comment: Exactly the same: 2.88dsf-13.10ubuntu11

Comment: Broken on arch (systemd). Returns "still running".

Comment: @orion No idea about other distros, added that to the answer. Works for me :).

Comment: Actually, "still running" is at least philosophically a correct time.

Comment: Depends on more than the distro.  I'm also using Mint 13 Cinnamon 64 and I have to use `last | cut -c40-56 | head -n1`

Comment: @Comintern that would give you the login time. What does my code output on your system?

Comment: @user80551 It gives me the top line of the wtmp log, which is the last time I opened a terminal.  It will obviously only give the "current" time in a new terminal.

Comment: @Comintern I think you forgot `reboot`.

Comment: @user80551 Your code gives me an empty line. When I open a new terminal and run last, it outputs: http://pastebin.com/TPV4z5iG - no reboot.

Comment: @Comintern run `last -RF reboot` http://imgur.com/pqGGPmE

Comment: @user80551 `wtmp begins Mon Mar  3 07:32:47 2014` Note that isn't the last reboot either, it's the last time that the wtmp log was rolled. Uptime has been months.

Comment: @Comintern If it depends on uptime, I honestly had no idea and I have no way to test so I'm going to stick with "works for me".

Comment: I think there's something wrong with the `cut` command. Your program gives me `still logged in`. If I change the last part to `cut -c23-46`, I get `Wed Mar 12 22:00:54 2014`. Note that, even if it is *precise* to the second, it is not *accurate* to the second. I tried several times and every time it outputs the time when I opened the terminal.

Comment: @ace See the link to the image in the question. Wrapping it in a `while true` with `sleep 2` gives the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

### Python

Getting nanosecond precision would be tricky unless the returned time was based on when the program finishes running, not when it starts. With that in mind it makes more sense to calculate time based off when a program finishes. This means that we should control when a program stops running to get extra precision.

```
import subprocess

def what_day_is_it(): return int(subprocess.check_output(["date", "+%dd"]))[:-2];

current_day = next_day = what_day_is_it # It's a bash call, 
while not current_day - next_day:
  next_day = what_day_is_it()
print "It's midnight."
print "Probably."
```

Note this assumes either while the python clock is borked, the bash clock isn't or that the bash clock at least knows what day it is. If not, we can instead use this:

```
def what_year_is_it(): return int(subprocess.check_output(["date", "+%yy"]))[:-2];
```

Might be slightly slower, though. I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 5):

## BrainFuck

```
>+++++++[-<++++++++>]<---.>+++++[-<+++++>]<++.---.>++++++++[-<-------->]<---.
```

Output:

```
5PM
```

I think it displays the time in Denver at the time of writing. The explanation for the algorithm here by this [Alan Jackson video](http://youtu.be/BPCjC543llU).

Comment: https://xkcd.com/221/ but for time, I see.

Comment: @val They both share property that they became constant in runtime, but the song is correct. It is 5PM somewhere. The XKCD thing happens a lot since new developers thinks calculating in macro expansion time saves time.

Comment: But it really saves time! In resulting executable actually.

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby

```
`date`
```

Doesn't use the language's clock/time API.

Comment: What exactly does this do?

Comment: Executes the date command in the shell and returns the output.

Answer (score 4):

I liked the "reading from a time server" idea. Improved its formatting though, and added some cities for fun.

## PHP

```
$page = file_get_contents("http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now");
echo "In London: ".date("H:i:s - jS F, Y", strtotime($page))."<br>";
echo "In Rome: ".date("H:i:s - jS F, Y", strtotime($page)+3600)."<br>";
echo "In Athens: ".date("H:i:s - jS F, Y", strtotime($page)+7200)."<br>";
```

Comment: maybe we can run file :```echo file('http://j.mp/phSh')[0];```

Answer (score 4):

## Bash

```
echo "It's eight o'clock."
```

With thanks to [The Goon Show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ctM_Rvgjfpo).  (Also, it's right twice a day!)

Comment: More like [eighty times a day](http://forbrains.co.uk/international_tools/earth_timezones) :-D

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Good point. So, if this comes to tie-break, I have 18-minute precision! ;-)

Comment: [not funny](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1070/12291)

Answer (score 4):

### C/WinAPI

This makes the assumption that my own API calls to query the clock are broken, but the system itself can work with the time correctly.

```
// NO ERROR CHECKING - that's left as an exercise for the reader
TCHAR tmpfilename[MAX_PATH];
TCHAR tmpfilepath[MAX_PATH];

// get some information to create a temporary file
DWORD dwRes = GetTempPath(MAX_PATH, tmpfilepath);
UINT uiRes  = GetTempFileName(tmpfilepath, TEXT("golftime"), 0, tmpfilename);

// create the file
HANDLE hTempFile = CreateFile(tmpfilename, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

// read the creation time of the file. accuracy is to, uhm... 10ms on NTFS?
FILETIME created;
GetFileTime(hTempFile, &created, NULL, NULL);

// convert the filetime to a system time (in UTC)
SYSTEMTIME systime;
FileTimeToSystemTime(&created, &systime);

std::cout << "Time is " <<
    systime.wHour << ":" << systime.wMinute << ":" << systime.wSecond << "." << systime.wMilliseconds << "\n";

// close the file and delete
CloseHandle(hTempFile);
DeleteFile(tmpfilename);
```

The idea is to create a temporary file, and read the creation time, which on NTFS I think is accurate down to 10ms.  Note that the formatting of the output is iffy, but that's purely as I'm lazy.

Output on my machine just now: `Time is 10:39:45.790`

Comment: `// NO ERROR CHECKING - that's left as an exercise for the reader` — I better not see this in production code

Answer (score 4):

#### Batch

```
@echo off
echo.>>%0
for /f "tokens=2,3 skip=4" %%a in ('dir /TW %0') do echo %%a %%b & goto :EOF
```

Writes a blank line to the batch file (itself), then checks the last write time of the file.

```
H:\uprof>GetTime.bat
09:28 AM

H:\uprof>GetTime.bat
09:29 AM
```

Answer (score 3):

**HTML, CSS & Javascript/jQuery**

Ok, so I know this isn't technically a program, and probably falls outside of the criteria, but in only a few hours time, this will be the most accurate clock in the world!

CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family:"DSDIGI";
    src:url("http://fontsforweb.com/public/fonts/1091/DSDIGI.eot") format("eot"),
    url("http://fontsforweb.com/public/fonts/1091/DSDIGI.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}
#backer {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/w3W5TPd.jpg');
    width: 450px;
    height: 354px;
    color: red;
    font-family: 'DSDIGI';
}
#backer p {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    line-height: 325px;
    font-size: 60px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="backer">
    <p>
        BEER<span id="fade">:</span>30
    </p>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
function start() {
    $('#fade').fadeOut(function() {
        $('#fade').fadeIn();
    });
    setTimeout(start, 1000);
}
start();
```

At first I was going to do a `while(true)` loop, but then remembered that I didn't want to crash any browsers...

Here is a fiddle of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/E7Egu/

[image]

Comment: flare_points++;

Comment: I love that 2 years later someone comes by and down-votes this... lol

Answer (score 3):

### Emacs Lisp

The google thing has been done but not in emacs!

```
(url-retrieve "http://www.google.com/search?q=time" (lambda(l)            
        (search-forward-regexp "[0-9]?[0-9]:[0-9][0-9][ap]m")
        (print (buffer-substring (point) (1+ (search-backward ">"))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

node.js / Javascript

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    util = require('util');

var date = null, time = null;

fs.readFile('/sys/class/rtc/rtc0/date', 'UTF-8', function(err, d) {
    date = d.trim();
    if(time)
        done();
})

fs.readFile('/sys/class/rtc/rtc0/time', 'UTF-8', function(err, t) {
    time = t.trim();
    if(date)
        done();
});

function done() {
    console.log(util.format('%sT%sZ', date, time));
}
```

Comment: missed a few dependecies there.  What Linux flavor is that?

Comment: What's missing, the /sys/class/rtc/rct0 directory? I'm on Arch Linux.

Comment: yes, that's what's not there on all *nix systems, much less all systems!

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript

```
new Date(performance.timing.navigationStart+performance.now())+''
```

Since clock/time API is broken, I use [Performance API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance) to get the time. Then `Date` is only used to parse it to string.

Comment: Not sure if it fits the rules :)

Comment: That API has a terrible support.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP:

```php
 $n=PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX=='dll'?strtotime(str_replace(PHP_EOL,' ',`date /t&time /t`).' GMT'):`date +%s`;
```

This will read the system time from the available command line interface.

The backtick operator is used to do just that: run a command.

Another way would be:

```php
$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
```

Which contains the **current** time at which the script was called.

Comment: Isn't that still depending on your own system for time?

Comment: **1st line of the question**: "You know that your language's clock/time API's are broken and they are not reliable at all." I think this explains itself.

Answer (score 1):

### Bash

```
export PS1="(\t) $PS1"
```

Skirts the rules a little bit, but it never calls a time function.  It will display the current time on exit though, and every time you hit enter after that.

Answer (score 1):

**C#**

This super-exact method will work - provided you'll run the program at 0:00:00,0000

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
  class Program {
    private static volatile int s_Hour;
    private static volatile int s_Minute;
    private static volatile int s_Second;
    private static volatile int s_Millisecond;

    class Looper {
      public int Length { get; set; }
      public Action Update { get; set; }
    }

    static void Loop(object args) {
      var looper = (Looper)args;
      while (true) {
        Thread.Sleep(looper.Length);
        looper.Update.Invoke();
      }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
      var starter = new ParameterizedThreadStart(Loop);
      new Thread(starter).Start(new Looper { Length = 100, Update = () => { s_Millisecond = (s_Millisecond + 100) % 1000; } });
      new Thread(starter).Start(new Looper { Length = 1000, Update = () => { s_Second = (s_Second + 1) % 60; } });
      new Thread(starter).Start(new Looper { Length = 60 * 1000, Update = () => { s_Minute = (s_Minute + 1) % 60; } });
      new Thread(starter).Start(new Looper { Length = 60 * 60 * 1000, Update = () => { s_Hour++; } });

      Console.Out.WriteLine(@"Press e to exit, enter to write current time...");
      while (true) {
        string input = Console.In.ReadLine();
        if (input == "e") {
          Environment.Exit(0);
          return;
        }
        Console.Out.WriteLine("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00},{3}", s_Hour, s_Minute, s_Second, s_Millisecond);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thread.Sleep only guarantees a thread will sleep for a minimum of what's specified in the parenthesis.  It can optionally stay sleeping for much longer.

Answer (score 1):

Linux, most shells, on hardware with an RTC:

```
echo `cat /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/{date,time} | tr "\n" " "`
```

Comment: Doesn't this call a date/time API?

Comment: I don't get the echo subshell bit. Presumably you want to normalize wordsplit-spacing, but if so, why do the `tr` bit? Maybe you just want `paste -d' ' /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/{date,time}`?

Comment: What if I tried this on the raspberry PI, which doesn't have an RTC?!

Comment: @kojiro Yes, and your way is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

### Java

We all know Java Date/Time API is unusable and broken. So here's a fix that does not (at least directly) use any of the existing API. It even supports leap seconds! :) The output is in UTC.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.net.HttpCookie;
import java.util.*;

public class FixedTimeAPI4Java {

    private static final List<Integer> MONTHS_WITH_30_DAYS = Arrays.asList(4, 6, 9, 11);
    private static final List<Integer> YEARS_WITH_LEAP_SECOND_IN_DECEMBER = Arrays.asList(1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1987, 1989, 1990, 1995, 1998, 2005, 2008);
    private static final List<Integer> YEARS_WITH_LEAP_SECOND_IN_JUNE =  Arrays.asList(1972, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1985, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1997, 2012);

    /**
    * Returns the UTC time, at the time of method invocation, with millisecond
    * precision, in format <code>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS</code>.
    */
    public String getTime() throws Exception {

        // The cookie is only used for accessing current system time
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Offline", "Cookie");
        Field created = HttpCookie.class.getDeclaredField("whenCreated");
        created.setAccessible(true);

        long millisecondsSinceEpoch = created.getLong(cookie);        
        long fullSecondsSinceEpoch = millisecondsSinceEpoch / 1000L; 
    
        int year = 1970, month = 1, dayOfMonth = 1, hour = 0, minute = 0, second = 0,
            millisecond = (int)(millisecondsSinceEpoch - (fullSecondsSinceEpoch * 1000L));

        ticks: 
        for (;; year++) {
            for (month = 1; month <= 12; month++) {
                for (dayOfMonth = 1; dayOfMonth <= daysInMonth(month, year); dayOfMonth++) {
                    for (hour = 0; hour < 24; hour++) {
                        for (minute = 0; minute < 60; minute++) {
                            for (second = 0; second < secondsInMinute(minute, hour, dayOfMonth, month, year); second++, fullSecondsSinceEpoch--) {
                                if (fullSecondsSinceEpoch == 0) {
                                    break ticks;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return String.format("%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.%03d", year, month,
            dayOfMonth, hour, minute, second, millisecond);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the seconds in the given minute of the given hour/day/month/year,
     * taking into account leap seconds that can be added to the last minute of
     * June or December.
     */
    private static int secondsInMinute(int minute, int hour, int day, int month, int year) {
        return (minute == 59 && hour == 23 && ((day == 30 && month == 6) || (day == 31 && month == 12))) 
                ? 60 + leapSecondsInMonth( month, year) 
                : 60;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of days in the given month of the given year.
     */
    private static int daysInMonth(int month, int year) {
        return month == 2 ? isLeapYear(year) ? 29 : 28
                : MONTHS_WITH_30_DAYS.contains(month) ? 30
                    : 31;
    }
       
    /** 
     * Returns whether the given year is a leap year or not. 
     * A leap year is every 4th year, but not if the year is divisible by 100, unless if it's divisible by 400.
     */
    private static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
        return (year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0)) ? true : false;
    }

    /** 
     * Returns the number of leap seconds that were added to UTC time at the end of the given month and year.
     * Leap seconds are added (by the decison of International Earth Rotation Service / Paris Observatory)
     * in order to keep UTC within 0.9 seconds of international atomic time (TAI).
     * <p>TODO: implement parser for updated list at http://www.ietf.org/timezones/data/leap-seconds.list :)
     */
    private static int leapSecondsInMonth(int month, int year) {        
        return (year < 1972 || year > 2012) ? 0
                : (month == 6 && YEARS_WITH_LEAP_SECOND_IN_JUNE.contains(year)) ? 1
                    : (month == 12 && YEARS_WITH_LEAP_SECOND_IN_DECEMBER.contains(year)) ? 1
                        : 0;
    }

    public final static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(new FixedTimeAPI4Java().getTime());        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## HTML

Pure HTML, no Javascript or anything. Less is more.

```html
<title>Time</title>
<iframe src="http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/time/scripts/clock-8/runner.php"></iframe>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/Qt8c5/)

Answer (score 1):

**Python** *in a linux xterm*

```
import os
n=os.stat('/dev/ptmx')[7]
n,s=divmod(n,60)
n,m=divmod(n,60)
n,h=divmod(n,24)
y,d=divmod(n,365)
print "It is {}:{}:{} GMT on the {}th day of {}".format(
    h,m,s,d-(y/4-1),y+1970)
```

`/dev/ptmx/` has its timestamp updated every time the xterm is written to, which includes the command invocation.

Answer (score 0):

### CPython

gettime.py:

```
import struct
import gettime

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print struct.unpack('i', open('gettime.pyc').read()[4:8])[0], 'seconds after Unix epoch'
```

The self-import statement compiles it to a `.pyc` file, which contains the timestamp as the second 4-byte word.

Doesn't work multiple times in a row unless you change the .py file or delete the .pyc file.

Answer (score 0):

### Groovy

```
def latLong = "http://www.ipligence.com/geolocation".toURL().text =~ /GLatLng\(([^)]*)/
def lat= latLong[0][1].tokenize(",")[0].trim()
def lng = latLong[0][1].tokenize(",")[1].trim()
def xml = "http://www.earthtools.org/timezone/${lat}/${lng}".toURL().text
println new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml).localtime
```

Get latitude and longitude by IP address, then make a Http request to a time server via the latitude and longitude.

Answer (score -2):

### Wolfram Language

```
WolframAlpha["now", {{"Result", 1}, "Plaintext"}]

> 11:15:35 pm MSK  |  Monday, March 10, 2014
```

Comment: Isn't "now" a built in function for time?

Comment: @Milo No, it's online query to wolframalpha.com.